# gh-pages : some pages missing (404)

Tags: angularjs, github, github-pages

I am trying to setup a github site: https://github.com/derlin/semantic-modals/tree/gh-pages. I use the `ng-include` directive, for example:

```
<div ng-include src="'_main.html'">
```

at different places, but none of them works.

I tried to rename my files, move them from the `html` folder to the root, I always end up with a 404.

I can display any of my files in the browser, for example: http://derlin.github.io/semantic-modals/vendor/semantic/semantic.min.css, but http://derlin.github.io/semantic-modals/_main.html or http://derlin.github.io/semantic-modals/_editModalContent.html systematically fail (even after move/rename).

Why are those files "invisible" for github.io while existant in the gh-pages branch of my repo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GH pages is assuming your branch is the output of a jekyll build, from the [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/)

> By default, Jekyll does not build any files or directories that
>
> - contain site content (indicated by names that start with _); or
>     are excluded in the site configuration.

The workaround is to create a file called `.nojekyll` in the root path to turn off Jekyll

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I already tried to rename the file. I just recommit the version with the `main.html` name, still the same trouble.

Comment: gosh, I really feel stupid. I forgot the `git add` command before commit. Great answer, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ng-include` in wrong way. See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), there are two ways (tag and attribute) and you have mixed them.

```
<ng-include
  src="string"
  [onload="string"]
  [autoscroll="string"]>
...
</ng-include>
```

and

```
<ANY
  ng-include="string"
  [onload="string"]
  [autoscroll="string"]>
...
</ANY>
```

You can use

```
<div ng-include="_main.html">
```

or

```
<ng-include src="_main.html">
```

but not mix them.

And look at [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/) in GitHub documentation. You need to rename files or make some manipulations to publish files which name is starting from underscore. By default they are hidden.

Comment: I will try. But how do you explain my files are not accessible from the browser?

Comment: It is what I thought: no difference. By the way, I always used the ng-include + src notation and it works in every app I made.

Comment: I see include of `main.html` in `index.html` source. But in repository you have `_main.html`. Maybe this is a case?

Comment: See update in my answer. I think that link to GitHub documentation will help you.